# Mocking stdin as a file

Tags: bash, shell, stdin

I have a Python script which needs a `--file xyz.json` argument.

Thing is, my JSON is immense, hence it is Gzipped. Of course I could un-gzip it and then run the script, but that seems wasteful. Is there a clever way I can get this to work while doing a `zcat xyz.json.gz | myscript.py --file ?????`. I don't want to go into modifying `myscript.py` to read stdin instead of a file unless there's no way to get this done otherwise.

Thanks!

Comment: What about bash **[Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html)**?  `myscript.py --file <( zcat file.gz )` ?  Note that this is likely just as wasteful -- though it might be more convenient.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
myscript.py --file <(zcat xyz.json.gz)
```

A file descriptor containing the pipe is returned. Provided that the script just reads the file, and does not search forward and backward, this should work.

The `<( ... )` is called [process substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst).

As an elaboration on what happens:

```
% awk 'BEGIN{print "filename:", ARGV[1]};1'  <(echo first; sleep 1; echo second) 
filename: /proc/self/fd/11
first
second
```

The `second` gets printed after a delay. So: Awk gets the filename `/proc/self/fd/11`, and starts to process it. It will immediately see the first line, and print it out. Then, after the sleep, it will see the second line, and print it as well.

Comment: Will this extract `xyz.json.gz` before executing the main command or will the contents 'stream' as the file decompresses?

Comment: This will produce a stream. It is like the python `yield`, or more precise, like a pipe.

Comment: I'm curious how this would work on the Python end. The code is expecting the --file argument to be a string file path, and it tries to open the file path with `open()`. So does this process substitution pass along a string which represents a temporary file?

Comment: Python will receive a file name like `/dev/fd/11` (although the exact name will depend somewhat on how `bash` implements process substitution on your particular platform).

Comment: @user1265125: It's easy enough to see for yourself. Just try `echo <(zcat xyz.json.gz)`, which will show you two things: first, what the name of the "file" is, and second that nothing is decompressed (since there  is no delay).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `/dev/stdin` or (equivalently) `/dev/fd/0`:

```
zcat xyz.json.gz | myscript.py --file /dev/stdin
zcat xyz.json.gz | myscript.py --file /dev/fd/0
```

Comment: That assumes `/dev/stdin` exists in your file system. `bash` only treats it specially if it is the target of a redirection.

Comment: @chepner: Interesting, OK. On what sort of system would `/dev/stdin` be missing?

Comment: Of most relevance is "Does Python treat the name `/dev/stdin` specially on a system without native support for `/dev/stdin`?" — to which I don't know the answer.  I know I added such support to one of my programs — oh, about 20 years ago, before it was anything like as widespread as it is now.  I don't know whether that's done by most people.